# Why does the IIS ServerManager class create my handler mapping disabled?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, servermanager

I want to add a handler mapping (script map) for our custom CGI-Exe to an Internet Information Server using the classes in the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace.
The (simplified) code is:

```cs
var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName);

Configuration webConfig = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration(siteName, appPath);
ConfigurationSection handlersSection = webConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers");

ConfigurationElementCollection handlersCollection = handlersSection.GetCollection();
string elementName = cgiFile + " script map appHost added by ACM";
ConfigurationElement addElement = handlersCollection.CreateElement("add");
addElement["allowPathInfo"] = true;
addElement["modules"] = "CgiModule";
addElement["name"] = elementName;
addElement["path"] = cgiFile;
addElement["requireAccess"] = "Execute";
addElement["scriptProcessor"] = Path.Combine(scriptsPath, cgiFile);
addElement["verb"] = "*";

handlersCollection.Add(addElement);
serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

This code adds the handler mapping to the mapping list in the IIS, but it is marked as disabled:
[image: screenshot of the disabled handler mapping in the IIS manager]

I have to manually select “Edit Feature Permissions…” from the Actions pane and select the “Execute” permission in the following dialog:

[image: screenshot of the Edit Feature Permissions dialog]

I want to know how to enable the handler mapping, either by setting different configuration options while creating the handler or by programmatically editing the feature permissions.

**Update**

I copied the web.config that was created as a result of this script, then I manually added the Execute permission with the dialog above and compared the resulting web.config to the original one:

The start changed from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
```

Now I need to find out, how to set the accessPolicy. But why is this set on the handlers node and not on my specific handler node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it helps just to formulate the question on stackoverflow. After playing with this for two days, I found the solution just hours after posting the question:

I needed to set the accessPolicy for the handlers.

After adding this line it finally worked:

```
handlersSection["accessPolicy"] = "Read, Script, Execute";
```

It seems I just used the wrong search terms, I looked for "edit feature permissions" instead of accessPolicy.

Comment: Remove "Execute" access from any "Upload" folder to avoid hacks via upload of ASPX page.